# How to write custom willDisplayView or didDisplayView for custom classes?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently working on writing my own kit for a custom table style view. My custom view will have it's own version of `TableCells` and I want to write methods that are called for `willDisplayCell` `didDisplayCell` etc. I just don't know how to get them to be called before they show up and after they showed up? Any advice or known tutorials for this?

Comment: Subclassing UITableViewCell would not do?

Comment: I'm actually subclassing from `UIView` for each `CustomCell` I guess I could use `viewDid` etc. from that. I'm still curious how you would write it from scratch.